# Not able to use System.Management.dll in Dot Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

How should I gather Hardware Info if `System.Management.dll` is not compatible with **Dot Net Core**.

How do I get the Machine info like Processor Id, Disk Volume number etc.

Comment: Guess you have to define machine you are interacting with and then try to invoke native calls for such information (PInvokes for win machines).

Comment: For workaround I made it a nuget package installed in the new project  But its not recognizing the namespace. Not able to use classes. Its displaying build error

Comment: Its currently not possible, I have created an issue on their repo, which had some activity recently. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/3324#issuecomment-262651454

Comment: Here is the thread to track on your issue https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14762

Answer (score 31):

.NET Core 3 now supports System.Management. As of this time, .NET Core 3 is in preview mode with preview 4 as the most current.

You will have to select the **Manage NuGet packages...** menu item under the Project menu in Visual Studio to install the latest version of `System.Management`. Make sure that the *include previews* checkbox is selected so that you will install the latest version.

The previous version of `System.Management` throws an error:

> "Cannot marshal a string by-value with the [Out] attribute..."

See [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/35694) for more info about the error.

Comment: System.Management is still not cross platform. It works on Windows but not on unix environments.

Comment: .Net Core version: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/

Answer (score 8):

I am currently porting a Net Framework project that uses `System.Management` to get some hardware info, and I also got to a dead end because `System.Management` is not compatible with Net Core.

The workaround I found was to use `Process.Start` from `System.Diagnostics` to execute powershell commands to get that information, for instance, to get the motherboard serial number you can use the command `Get-WmiObject Win32_BaseBoard | select SerialNumber`, you can then change the command to process the output and only have the serial number, or even process the output programatically.

You can also add some `ifs`, that depending on the current OS you can provide to the `Process.Start` specific OS commands, for instance, for linux you would need to process a dmidecode related command.

The only negative side in this approach is that its A LOT SLOWER whem compared with `System.Management`.

Comment: This is still the best workaround when working on different platforms in 2020, which is a shame. `Process.Start` the CLI depending on the OS you're running on and parse the result in the redirected output and return it and process as needed.

Comment: do you  install *Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility* ?

Comment: And Nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/ ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to install `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` in your .Net core project to be able to reference `System.Management.dll`.

Comment: Nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/ and *Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility* too ?

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue while upgrading from .NetFramework to .NetCore 3.0

> .NetFramework compatible System.Management won't work for the dotnet core, so to fix the issue just add a .Net core compatible System.Management nuget.

At this point the latest available version is 4.6.0 https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/4.6.0 and latest preview is 4.7.0-preview3.19551.4

Comment: *5.0.0*  https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/  - _When using NuGet 3.x this package requires at least version 3.4._

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`dotnet add package System.Management --version 8.0.0`