# How To Get Details of USB Device in C# .net Core Cross platform

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0, system.management, avalonia

I am working on Avalonia framework and .net core 3.0 using System.Management library to get USB device Details connected on pc. It works on windows. But when I test on mac and Linux , the application throws PlatformNotSupported Exception and says System.Management will only works on windows platform. So can anyone suggest me the alternate option or any configuration so that I could Solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to use System.Management.dll in Dot Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567595/not-able-to-use-system-management-dll-in-dot-net-core)

Comment: Hi @Suresh, I'm in stock with this issue. Do you find any solution? Thanks.

Comment: In same boat, need a good answer as well. I'm currently using python to do it but trying to get away from it.